# ValidationException when upgrading esapi 2.2.0.0 to 2.3.0.0

Tags: esapi

javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:359)

tried adding esapi.properties file with the following line as mention in your other chat under src/resources

ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory

Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Marking this as a permanent wiki answer.

Logging configuration instructions are here:

https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Configuration-Reference:-JavaLogFactory

Any other questions on this topic should be posted to the github discussions page.  I'm providing the link because if I copied the text per normal SO operating procedure any changes to the wiki will not be reflected in this question.

Comment: Thanks for beating me to this. You saved me a step of looking up the link!

Comment: @KevinW.Wall while its still another link, please mark future SO questions about this issue as a duplicate of this one.  I made it a wiki for that reason.